# Viewing detailed info for Stored Procedure compilation error(PL/SQL: ORA-00933)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, select-into

This procedure is supposed to copy user info from one table to another. It is executed with spring mybatis, and the spring retrieves some results by procedure's parameters.

There is a compilation error at `SELECT ... INTO ...` statement.

> `PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`, and `PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

The create procedure command is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_MIGRATE_USER" (
    p_ID OUT NUMBER,
    p_USERNAME OUT VARCHAR2,            -- `p_USERNAME OUT VW_OUT_USER.USERNAME%TYPE,` also same error
    p_REG_DATE OUT DATE,
    p_USER_ID IN NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT T.USERNAME
    INTO p_USERNAME                     -- PL/SQL: SQL Statement ingored
    FROM VW_OUT_USER AS T
    WHERE T.ID = p_USER_ID;             -- PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    SELECT SEQ_TB_USER.NEXTVAL, SYSDATE
    INTO p_ID, p_REG_DATE
    FROM DUAL;

    INSERT INTO TB_USER (
        ID
        , USERNAME
        , REG_DATE
        , EXT_USER_ID
    ) VALUES (
        p_ID
        , p_USERNAME 
        , p_REG_DATE
        , P_USER_ID
    );
    
END;
```

I searched but couldn't find an answer.

The Oracle version is `Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production`

Comment: Your first query's *from_clause* is syntactically incorrect. It should be `FROM VW_OUT_USER T` and not `FROM VW_OUT_USER AS T`.

Comment: The errors you show are not complete. They should include a line *and* column number that point you *precisely* at the word `AS` in that statement.

Comment: Your use of double quotes is redundant because the procedure name, without the double quotes, is translated to uppercase.

Comment: @JeffHolt I executes the query with Navicat, and I couldn't see any _line and column number_ for error message. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Then query `USER_ERRORS`, which is what the sqlplus `show errors` command does or what sqldeveloper does by default. Use the sharpest tool in the shed and you actually willl *not* cut yourself.

Comment: @JeffHolt I've just realized that `AS` for table alias is invalid in oracle. :) It was the solution. Thanks. But when I query `USER_ERRORS` it says `ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement` what is the alternative query for detailed errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you found the culprit, this is related to comment you posted about viewing *detailed errors*.

This is an example which simulates what you did - used `as` with a table alias:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test as
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*)
  5      into l_cnt
  6      from emp as e;
  7  end;
  8  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
```

If you used SQL*Plus (like I did), you could simply type `show err`:

```
SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE P_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/14     PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

It says that you should look at line #6, position (column) #14:

```
3  begin
<snip>
6      from emp as e;      --> line 6
   12345678901234
                ^
                |
              position 14 - as you can see, it points to "as"
```

If tool you use doesn't support such a command, you can always query `user_errors` and get the same information:

```
SQL> select line, position, text
  2  from user_errors
  3  where name = 'P_TEST'
  4  order by line, position;

      LINE   POSITION TEXT
---------- ---------- -------------------------------------------------------
         4          3 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
         6         14 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

SQL>
```

Comment: sql developer makes seeing this error easy...

Comment: Some other tools as well (such as TOAD). I just can't NOT think about times when all we had was SQL*Plus.

Comment: And when there was only UFI, my life wasn't so streamlined.

Comment: I've learned a lot. I thought that `USER_ERRORS` is a query, not a table. What a poor knowledge :(

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.